# Titanium Studio iOS app fails to build

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

This is the error I am getting:

```
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp.app/myApp normal i386
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
```

I tried cleaning the project, it didn't work.

The application is located locally on my laptop, and not on a server (if this information matters).

Comment: Are you using some module?

Comment: @Wahhab_mirza, but I've made sure the modules are cross platform.

Comment: Try removing the module references from tiapp.xml and re-build, does it work? Also try manually deleting the iphone folder from the /build folder.